# Why does Scala PartialFunction isDefinedAt method always return true?

Tags: scala, partialfunction

my code is as below.

```scala
    case class C[T]() {
      val pf:PartialFunction[Any,Any] = {
        case i:T => i
      }
    }

    println(C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt(-1.0))
```

this prints `true`. Why this happens?

Comment: That will never work due erasure and other things, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want `C[T]` acts like some kind of filter.  It is supposed to work as `C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt(e)` . When `e is of type Int`, it should return `true`, otherwise `false`

Comment: Yeah I get that, but why do you want that? What is the broader usecase?

Answer (score 2):

Due to type erasure your code is basically equal to:

```
case class C[T]() {
  val pf:PartialFunction[Any,Any] = {
    case i:Any => i // this matches everything
  }
}
```

you can use `TypeTag`s to fix it:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
case class C[T: TypeTag]() {
  def pf[U: TypeTag]: PartialFunction[U, Any] = {
    case i if typeOf[U] <:< typeOf[T] => i
  }
}
```

in use:

```
@ C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt("")
res41: Boolean = false

@ C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt(34)
res42: Boolean = true
```

these are virtually equal to

```
@ C[Int]().pf[String].isDefinedAt("")
res41: Boolean = false

@ C[Int]().pf[Int].isDefinedAt(34)
res42: Boolean = true
```

where the type `U` is inferred - it has a limitation that it can only be as precise as compiler's knowledge about the type when `TypeTag` is required.

You can also try to use `ClassTag[T]` to use runtime reflection... but it would fail for primitives

```
case class C[T]()(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) {
  def pf[U: TypeTag]: PartialFunction[U, Any] = {
    case i if classTag.runtimeClass.isInstance(i) => i
  }
}
```

which results in

```
@ C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt(34)
res2: Boolean = false

@ C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt("")
res3: Boolean = false
```

Thing is `classTag` would resolve to Scala's `int` while runtime would show `java.lang.Int`:

```
@ case class C[T]()(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) {
    def pf: PartialFunction[Any, Any] = {
      case i => println(s"T = ${classTag.runtimeClass.getName}, here: ${i.getClass.getName}")
    }
  }
defined class C

@ C[Int]().pf.isDefinedAt(34)
res7: Boolean = true

@ C[Int]().pf(34)
T = int, here: java.lang.Integer
res8: Any = ()
```

In general there is no perfect solution here, you can read more about similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628379/how-to-know-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-typetags-type).