# Get generic types of child in scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection

```
class Parent[T: ClassTag] {
}

class Child[U: ClassTag, T: ClassTag] extends Parent[T] {
}

val o: Parent[_] = new Child[Int, String]
```

Is it possible to get the actual types of **T** and **U** given **o** (note its type **Parent[_]**), assuming you know **o** is of type **Child**?

I have tried a few things based on [Runtime resolution of type arguments using scala 2.10 reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458502/runtime-resolution-of-type-arguments-using-scala-2-10-reflection) but no luck so far.

Comment: How do you want to get them?

Comment: Ultimately as strings, for instance in the example given that would be "Int" and "String"

Comment: But how? Is it okay if each class stores the `ClassTag`? Should some method reveal them? Not sure what you intend to use them for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify `Parent` and `Child` slightly (note that `: ClassTag` notation is basically the same except for `val`, so it doesn't give a name to the implicit parameter or make it accessible from outside the class)

```
class Parent[T](implicit val tTag: ClassTag[T]) {
}

class Child[U, T](implicit override val tTag: ClassTag[T], val uTag: ClassTag[U]) extends Parent[T] {
}
```

then you can do

```
val tTag = o.tTag // ClassTag[String]
```

Of course, if you need `uTag`, you'll have to cast: `o.asInstanceOf[Child[_, _]].uTag`, but it'll work

> assuming you know o is of type Child