# to build a generic cast function in scala

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'd like to build a function to read the settings from a properties file, key/value pairs, and then cast it to expected types. If the given field name does't exist, we get the default value of the specific T. Is that doable?

I put some pseudo code here and would like to know how to write the real code with the help of scala reflection.

```
def getField[T](fieldName: String): T =
{
  val value = getField(fieldName)

  if (value == null) {
    T match {
     case Int => 0
     case Boolean => false
     ...
     case _ => null
   }
  }
  else value.asInstanceOf[T]    
}
```

Alternatively, throw an exception if the field is not locate, which is not a bad idea to me...
    def getField[T](fieldName: String): T =
    {
      val value = getField(fieldName)

```
  if (value == null) {
    throw new Exception("error msg")
   }
  }
  else value.asInstanceOf[T]    
}
```

I know how to do it if it returns Option[T] (as discussed here [Writing a generic cast function Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059451/writing-a-generic-cast-function-scala) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use implicit parameter to pass default value. It will give you 100% type safety + easy way to override defaults not only for simple type, but for any other types.

```
  trait DefaultValue[T] {
    def default: T
  }

  object DefaultValue {
    def apply[T](value: T) = new DefaultValue[T] {
      val default: T = value
    }
  }

  trait LowLevelDefaultImplicits {
    implicit val intDefaultValue = DefaultValue[Int](0)
    implicit val booleanDefaultValue = DefaultValue[Boolean](false)
  }

  object MyDefaults extends LowLevelDefaultImplicits {
    // Easy to override defaults
    implicit val trueByDefault = DefaultValue[Boolean](true)
  }

  import MyDefaults._

  def readField(s: String): Any = ... some extern service call ...

  def getField[T: DefaultValue](fieldName: String): T =
  {
    val value = readField(fieldName)

    if (value == null)
      implicitly[DefaultValue[T]].default
    else
      value.asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  println(getField[Int]("aaa"))
  println(getField[Boolean]("aaa"))
```

Result:

```
0
true
```

^ - as you can see default "false" was overridden by higher priority implicit.

One drawback - you need to define defaults for all types T. But I think it's a benefit. By providing defaults for each type you get rid of 'null' values.

Comment: or use the already existing http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc.sxr/scalaz/Zero.scala.html

Answer (score -1):

You can always take an object oriented way:

```
case class GetField[A](default: A) {
  def apply(field: Any): A = try {
    field.asInstanceOf[A]
  } catch {
    case e: NullPointerException => ???
    case e: ClassCastException => default
  }
}

def readField(key: String): Any = ???

val field = readField("foo")
val bool = GetField(false)(field)
val int = GetField(0)(field)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use

```
value.asInstanceOf[T]
```

If `value` is `null`, this returns the default value of the type `T`. So 0 for numbers, `false` for booleans, and so on. This is specified somewhere in the Scala spec.