# Spark Scala generic min() function

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark

How can I create a generic `min()` function in Spark which returns a value of the same type as the generic used?

Here's what I have for doubles and strings:

```
def minDouble(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]], field: String): Double = {
  rdd.map(row => row(field).toDouble).min()
}

def minString(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]], field: String): String = {
  rdd.map(row => row(field)).min()
}
```

How can I use generics to make this a single function? And make it extensible so that I could add other types.

Here's my attempt:

```
def minGeneric[V : Manifest](rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]], field: String)(implicit ord: Ordering[V]): V = {
  rdd.map(row => cast[V](row(field))).min().get
}
```

which uses the `cast()` function from [Writing a generic cast function Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059451/writing-a-generic-cast-function-scala)

When I run this, I get a `NoSuchElementException: None.get`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
        at SimpleApp$.statMinGeneric(SimpleApp.scala:67)
        at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:34)
        at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Why is it returning None here? I am I taking the right approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an option of passing casting function like `_.toDouble`?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Can you give an example of how that would work?

Comment: Maybe it is not matching or it is not saying it is of the type. Could you maybe post your sample usage?

Comment: @JustinPiphony Here's how I use it:

```minGeneric[Double](maps, "wage")```

Comment: I don't know that this is possible without a hint to cast like Dmitry is suggesting. A string is not directly castable to another type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an option of passing additional param to your function, you can do following:

```
def minCasted[A](caster: String => A)(rdd: RDD[Map[String, String]], field: String): A = {
    caster(rdd.map(_(field)).min())
}

def minDouble = minCasted(_.toDouble) _

def minString = minCasted(identity[String]) _
```